# Why did Marisol approach Billy in the first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, goliath

In the beginning of season 2 of Goliath, Marisol approaches Billy on the peer and asks him to help Julio. Ultimately she ends up killing Julio and trying to kill Billy as well. What was the point of her getting Billy involved then?